# angular object filter and orderBy

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have receive object from server like this:

```
Object {
0: "girl night", 
1: "martini", 
2: "burger", 
3: "folk", 
4: "laughter house"
}
```

With ng-repeat it can display properly but when I user filter or orderBy, I get this error.

```
<ion-list> <ion-item ng-repeat="item in MyKeyword" ng-click="changeText(item)">{{item}}</ion-item> </ion-list>
```

> ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but
>   received: {"0":"girl
>   night","1":"martini","2":"burger","3":"folk","4":"laughter house"}

How can I use filter to make work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to generate quick code that would emulate what you trying to achieve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <body>

    <div ng-init="data={'0': 'first', '1': 'second', '2': 'third'}">
        <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</li>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <div ng-init="data=['first', 'second', 'third']">
        <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</li>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and seems to me that your iteration is just fine. You can use `ng-repeat`to iterate through either array or object.

From your code I am not able to see where you actually use filter, so wouldn't know what goes wrong really.

The hint, however, is that in javascript arrays are actually objects, with additional methods, and properties, eg.: `forEach` or `length`. My assumption would be that your filter, wherever it is and whatever it does, is trying to iterate through array.

**from script**

In that case **before** you use it, you could just convert your object to an array with this bit of code.

```
var arr = [];
for (var item in object) { 
    arr.push(object[item]); 
}
```

Or, if you want to store indexes as well you would need array of objects. You can achieve it with this:

```
var arr = [];
for (var item in object) { 
    arr.push({ id: item, value: object[item] }); 
}
```

Once you have your array use, filter on it.

**from HTML**

If you want to do it from HTML level you can use `ng-repeat` with `key` `value` syntax.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="(key, value) in MyKeyword">{{value}}</ion-item>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank IndieForger, I convert object to array by your code and it work.

Answer (score 1):

The error itself is mentioning the reason explicitly. You can't iterate like that over a json object. Ideally, your response should be ["girl night", "martini", "burger", "folk", "laughter house"] for that way to work.

If you don't want to change the service response format. Then, iterate like this.

```
<ion-list> <ion-item ng-repeat="(key, value) in MyKeyword" ng-click="changeText(value)">{{value}}</ion-item> </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your given object into an array then you can do the ng-repeat on it.

in JS:

```
   var convertedToArray = Object.keys(MyKeyword).map(function (key) {return obj[key]});
```

in HTML:

```
<ion-list> <ion-item ng-repeat="item in convertedToArray" ng-click="changeText(item)">{{item}}</ion-item> </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

filter only support array, but your server return object obviously. So you have to convert object to array.

A simple way to do this conversion is use underscore.js. like:

_.values({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3});
=> [1, 2, 3]

So the scenario is to
1 make your own filter maybe named as toArray, in the filter you use underscore to convert to array and return.
2 use normal filter to filter again.
3 the template will look like:

ng-repeat="item in MyKeyword|toArray|filter:xxx"